# How do I skip a rake task

Tags: rake

Consider the following Rake tasks:

```
task deploy => [:package] do
end

task package => [:build] do
end

task build do
end
```

Is there a way to invoke Rake on the command line to execute the package and deploy tasks, but not the build task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no.

The way I usually go about this is instead of using the dependant task notion like you have above:

```
task deploy => [:package] do
end
```

I create an alias task for whatever action that is to be completed:

```
task all => [:build, :package, :deploy]

task fastDeploy => [:package, :deploy]

task deploy do
end

task package do
end

task build do
end
```

It's not very elegant, but I do find it to be more readable and you can visibly see the dependency of tasks on other tasks instead of the kind of spaghetti code structure the dependant notion can result in... when you have a lot of task it can be awkward to debug the logic to figure what's gone wrong and where at times.

Hope this helps.